# Call exe from different server in php script

Tags: php, client-server, exec

I have two server. The first one has php script and the second one is keep my exe file. How can I connect to second server in php script to use exe.
The php script will take the input file, connect the second server, run the exe with input parameter and get output file.

I m only curious about how I can connect the second server in php script

Comment: I really do not recommend you to do that... even if it was possible, wich i`m not sure, it`s very dangerous...

Answer (score 0):

Make your second server accessible through http (apache, php, etc). Then create a script that accepts a parameter, and run the exe file using a system call, then call the script inside the 2nd server from your first server.

Comment: I don't know how I call that script